# How to set UID for composed mail in MailCore

Tags: ios, cocoa, imap, mailcore

I am preparing the Mail iOS application using the MailCore framework. While composing the new mail, How I set the UID for my mails, as mails are sending but it is not moves or copied to the sent box or to the draft folder. When I copy or move the message it get crashed on the line..

```
NSString *uid = [msg uid];
```

At the CTCoreFolder Class, in these method ..

```
- (void)copyMessage: (NSString *)path forMessage:(CTCoreMessage *)msg
- (void)moveMessage: (NSString *)path forMessage:(CTCoreMessage *)msg
```

as I am creating and sending the message by this way....

```
CTCoreMessage *msg = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];
 CTCoreAddress *fromAddress = [[CTCoreAddress alloc] initWithName:@"name" email:@"name@mailserver.com"];
  CTCoreAddress *address3 = [[CTCoreAddress alloc] initWithName:@"person" email:@"person@rcscentralmail.com"];

 [msg setFrom:[NSSet setWithObject:fromAddress]];
    [msg setTo:[NSSet setWithObject:address3]];
[msg setSubject:@"Test simple appfdgfghbfghb"];

[CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:msg server:@"mail.mailserver.com" username:@"abc@mailserver.com"
                         password:@"abcdef" port:587 useTLS:NO useAuth:YES];
```

After calling Connecting to server I am calling move or copy method like ::

```
[folder moveMessage:@"INBOX.Sent" forMessage:message];
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the error when it crashes?  There isn't enough here to see, but it looks like you might be trying to move messages around without creating an instance of `CTCoreMessage`?

Comment: It does not produce any error just crashed. I have modified my question now hope it is clear where I am lacking ..

Comment: Can you please add the code showing how you connect to the server via IMAP?  All you've shown is SMTP, followed by an IMAP method, but theres nothing to help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks James for your support... I got the solution, You can't set the UID, the UID is only assigned by the server. You'll need to append the message to the Sent or Draft mailboxes, this can be done using -(BOOL)append:(CTCoreMessage*) which is on CTCoreFolder. However this method is only in the newest version of MailCore. The changeset can be seen here:

```
https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/commit/1f64ed5b56fc995613f8fc2dd33d3ff45fe140d0
```

Thanks to Matt Ronge.